# Reduce checking for a long list of IFs

Tags: c#, list, if-statement

```
if (Settings.EnableColors)
{
    if (Settings.EnableRed) { content.Add("Color red", Color.Red);}
    if (Settings.EnableGreen) { content.Add("Color green", Color.Green);}
    if (Settings.EnableBlue) { content.Add("Color blue", Color.Blue);}
    if (Settings.EnableYellow) { content.Add("Color yellow", Color.Yellow);}
}
```

The list contains more than 1000 entries, and every few minutes this "if statements" must be checked if true or false.
Is there any other way around to have them saved in a profile list or something, and that list to be loaded on demand...?
Or any faster method to check them?

Comment: if you want to shorten the code, maybe. If you want to reduce the if checks. most likely a no

Comment: Why do you need to check it every few minutes? If these are the application settings, you know there is a [`SettingChanging`-event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.settingchanging(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: It looks like a good place, to use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` collection

Comment: Is it your code that's changing the settings?  If so, you don't need to wait a couple of minutes to test all these values; simply make whatever changes you need *when you change the value*.

Comment: @adv12 Nope, an user is checking whatever he needs, and the list is changing every 10-20 min. Than the program must check what user have checked and compare with the updated list.

Comment: 1000 entries??? This seems like a huge amount of settings. What exactly are you doing on a more general basis?

Comment: Seeing as you only want to modify what has changed since the last check, couldn't you just track the changes rather than run through the list each time?

Comment: @sr28 Yes, it's a huge list of settings, but more than half can be grouped and the list goes down to max 300. Still to much. What do you mean by "track the changes"?

Comment: Well, you say the user can change whatever they want and every 10-20mins the list is changed. So, you really only need to identify the differences at the latest check compared to the previous. As such, whenever a user changes something, track it by storing it in a dictionary or something. Then when it comes to updating the settings list you have already stored all the changes made and can simply update the list.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can create a Dictionary with *all* setiings and mark disabled with `null` values :

```
// if value is null then color is not enabled
private readonly Dictionary<string, Color?> _colors = new Dictionary<string, Color?>()
{
   { "red", Color.Red},  // is enabled
   { "green", null}      // is disabled
};
```

And then method that loops through this dictionary :

```
if (!Settings.EnableColors) { return; }

foreach(var kv in _colors)
{
    if(kv.Value.HasValue) { content.Add($"Color {kv.Key}", kv.Value);}
}
```

Alternatively you can use events :

```
public class ColorChangedEventArgs
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}

public event EventHandler<ColorChangedEventArgs> ColorSettingsChanged;
```

Then subscribe to it from some method :

```
ColorSettingChanged += (sender, args) => // ... use args here to access new value
```

And to fire event you can simply call :

```
ColorSettingChanged(this, new ColorChangedEventArgs{ Color = Color.Red, IsEnabled = true});
```

So the main picture is :

Whenever user changes settings  this `ColorSettingsChanged` event is fired and in a handler it is possible to access new setting via this `ColorChangedEventArgs` instance and take appropriate action.

Comment: I will try this for now and see the results.Thank you!